# How to enable SASL mechanism in kafka locally

Tags: apache-kafka, jaas, sasl

How to enable SASL mechanism with **JAAS** Authentication for kafka ? thus the consumer/producer have to provide username & password in order to be able to publish in the broker
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of enabling SASL authentication in Kafka is extensively described in the [Authentication using SASL section](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl) in the documentation. I suggest you follow the official documentation as it contains instructions for all the mechanisms and recommendations for production environments.

To give a bit of background, at a glance you need to:

1. Create a JAAS file for brokers with a `KafkaServer` block and the configuration for the specific mechanism.
2. Add `-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<PATH_TO_JAAS_FILE>` to your broker JVM command line argument.
3. Configure client to use SASL via the `security.protocol`, `sasl.mechanism` and `sasl.jaas.config` settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mickael. I'm struggeling to configure the clients, may you give a bit example about your 3rd point please

Comment: For example for PLAIN, your client needs:
```
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
    username="<USERNAME>" \
    password="<PASSWORD>";
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
```
See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_plain_clientconfig

Comment: I was able to connect the producer by adding all the config (above) in the `producer.properties`, so we don't need to have an extra config-file. Thanks Mickael

Comment: !important: when launching the producer we have to specify the config by adding `--producer.config    config/producer.properties`

Comment: how to add the parameter of step2 to JVM ?

Comment: If you use the Kafka scripts, like kafka-console-producer, you can just set and export KAFKA_OPTS. For example, export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<PATH_TO_JAAS_FILE>".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71496266/7691891