# Kafka SASL_SSL No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, jaas, sasl

I'm trying to activate authentication using SASL/PLAIN in my kafka broker.

the JAAS configuration file is as the following

```
KafkaServer {
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
    username="admin"
    password="admin-secret"
    user_admin="admin-secret"
    user_alice="alice-secret";
};
```

I launch kafka service using the following commands

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=<PATH>kafka_server_jaas.conf
/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /config/server.properties
```

The kafka service is not started properly and I got these errors in the log

```
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file: '/home/kafka/kafka/config/kafka_server_jaas.conf'.
    at org.apache.zookeeper.client.ZooKeeperSaslClient.<init>(ZooKeeperSaslClient.java:189)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1161)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1210)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,587] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,588] ERROR [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Auth failed, initialized=false connectionState=CONNECTING (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,592] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:46706, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,611] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, session id = 0x100002dd98c0000, negotiated timeout = 18000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,612] INFO [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Connected. (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,752] INFO [feature-zk-node-event-process-thread]: Starting (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureChangeListener$ChangeNotificationProcessorThread)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,786] INFO Feature ZK node at path: /feature does not exist (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureChangeListener)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,788] INFO Cleared cache (kafka.server.FinalizedFeatureCache)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,957] INFO Cluster ID = 6WTadNCMRAW4dHoc_JUnIg (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,968] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: The Cluster ID 6WTadNCMRAW4dHoc_JUnIg doesn't match stored clusterId Some(RJXzPwJeRfawIa_yA0B26A) in meta.properties. The broker is trying to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:228)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

I already added the following lines to `server.properties`

```
listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9092
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,968] ERROR Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
kafka.common.InconsistentClusterIdException: The Cluster ID 6WTadNCMRAW4dHoc_JUnIg doesn't match stored clusterId Some(RJXzPwJeRfawIa_yA0B26A) in meta.properties. The broker is trying to join the wrong cluster. Configured zookeeper.connect may be wrong.
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:228)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```

This issue occurs when there is a mismatch in cluster ID stored in Zookeeper and Kafka data directories for the broker.

In this case, cluster ID of the broker stored in

- Zookeeper data is `6WTadNCMRAW4dHoc_JUnIg`
- Kafka meta.properties is `RJXzPwJeRfawIa_yA0B26A`

**Reason:**
Zookeeper data directory got deleted.

Deleting Zookeeper `dataDir` and restarting both Zookeeper and Kafka service will not work. Because Zookeeper creates a new Cluster ID and assigns it to the broker when it registers and if there is no entry already. This new cluster ID will be different from the one in `meta.properties`.

This issue can be fixed by following below steps

- delete both Kafka `log.dirs` and Zookeeper `dataDir` - results in data loss; Both Kafka and Zookeeper service needs to be restarted
- delete `meta.properties` in Kafka `log.dirs` directory - no data loss; Kafka service needs to be started anyway
- update cluster ID in `meta.properties` with the value stored in Zookeeper data; In this case, replace `RJXzPwJeRfawIa_yA0B26A` with `6WTadNCMRAW4dHoc_JUnIg` - no data loss; Kafka service needs to be started anyway

`javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configuration file`

The `Client` section is used to authenticate a SASL connection with ZooKeeper. Above error `javax.security.auth.login.LoginException` is a warning and Kafka will connect to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication if Zookeeper allows it.

```
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,587] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,588] ERROR [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Auth failed, initialized=false connectionState=CONNECTING (kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,592] INFO Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:46706, server: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2022-03-16 12:13:16,611] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, session id = 0x100002dd98c0000, negotiated timeout = 18000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
```

The KafkaServer section is used by the Broker and provides SASL configuration options for inter broker connection. The username and password are used by the broker to initiate connections to other brokers. The set of properties user_username defines the passwords for all users to connect to the broker.